# Where can I find an official or recommended Windows desktop application user interface usability and style guide?

Tags: desktop-application, guidelines, windows-os, style

I've heard there is a OSX User Interface Usability and Style Guide since the 90's. I never heard of an equivalent book for Windows. Is there any?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows 7

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx

Windows XP

http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/System/platform/pcdesign/XPguidelines.mspx

Comment: Looks like you found your own answer.  BTW, there's also UI style guides for Java and GNOME platforms as well.  Guidelines are simply a way to keep your app from looking like a complete amateur wrote it.  Eventually you'll have to surpass the guidelines or thoughtfully decline their advice to address certain usability problems.

Comment: Agreed, though it's wise to adhere as much as possible to the guidelines to make your application appear seamless with the operating system's software and paradigms.

Comment: if you don't want to feel restricted by Adobe Reader; use the **`Guidelines`** subitem